# How to use phantomjs create gif?

Tags: javascript

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open("https://www.google.com/", function start(status) {
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
    page.render('google_home_'+i+'.gif', {format : "gif", quality: '100'});
    i++;
    if(i == 20)
    phantom.exit();
  }, 20);
});
```

Then the size of the google_home_1.gif is 0KB.
Can someone tell me why or tell me the right method to create a gif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**phanty.js** (Tweaked from the [quick-start](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html))

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://www.yahoo.com', function(status) {
    if (status === "success") {
        page.render('ping.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

**Shell commands** (Run in order)

```
phantomjs phanty.js         # Run phantom script
ffmpeg -i ping.png jif.gif  # Convert to gif
```

**Setup**

`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

**Reasoning**

[PhantomJS Render](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html) requires [Qt](https://www.qt.io/)

> GIF support depends on the build of Qt used

However the specs don't specify how to build Qt.  So I just went with a quick ffmpeg install (under 15 seconds to install).

Comment: Also the output file example.gif is 0KB and can't be open.

Comment: Err yeah I'm playing with it now.  Not outputting anything for me just yet.

Comment: I have used a lot lib which is focus on create gif, but also will occur

Comment: I got the png to output (answer updated), but the .gif isn't outputting anything for me.  [The docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html) say to just put .gif in the extension.  However they also say "GIF support depends on the build of Qt used"

Comment: Installing [QT](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) on my Ubuntu 16 machine now, may take a little while.

Comment: Answer updated with workaround solution getting to .gif in the end for me.

Comment: Err, I find little relevant information on the Internet.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Nothing, forget about it. Then your method is use ffmpeg to convert png to gif, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115688/discussion-between-anthony-astige-and-erickk).